# UINavigationBar right button too tall

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using custom images for UINavigationBars and UIToolbars. The problem i'm having is on 1 of my views that uses a UINavigationBar, the right button appears too tall
[image]
On the views that use a UIToolbar (modal views so no Nav bar) they look fine
[image]

What could be causing the button to be too large? I've tried adding the button in IB and also using code. Then set the image like this

```
UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBlue"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 8, 6, 8)];
        [self.connectButton setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a smaller button. You can do this in Preview - resize it. Make sure you have @2x sizes too. T cannot recall the recommended size for theses images - it's something like 30 points or so (search and you'll find it for sure).

Comment: The size of my image isn't the issue as I use the same resizable image for all the tab bar/nav bar buttons.

Comment: Well don't believe me but this happened to me. The word 'Connect' is long so system may be trying to make the background image 'proportional'. Change 'Connect' to 'Conn' see if height changes. Also nav bar behavior may be different than toolbar behavior.

Comment: It didn't change with a short title :-( I'll try a shorter image, but it's a small resizable image anyway. No harm in trying thanks

Comment: Resizeable means it can grow bigger not get smaller.

Comment: You where stop on, thank you. Why would a toolBar be able to reduce the image to the right size but a navBar can't?

Comment: Hah - ask Apple! I had the same problem (with Nav Bar). You were lucky I tripped on your question trolling for points this AM :-)